# How to precisely center bootstrap grid in html page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When creating an ordinary Grid in bootstrap with 3 rows as the following, the grid is always positioned towards the left of the page,

I've tried centering the entire grid towards the center with the help of `text-align:center` and also tried using css classes `center-block` and `text-center`

But the grid only barely moves towards the center area.

Any suggestions on how i can get this to work?

Also i require **Precise centering** not using offsets in bootstrap

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to get precise centering without using the offset classes: **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/834a866n/)**

Create a new helper class called `col-centered`:

```
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Any column you use this class on (ex. `class="col-md-7 col-centered"`) will be centered directly in the middle of its container.

Then, add another set columns around your three column grid:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <!-- New set of columns, centered -->
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-centered">
            <!-- New row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Block
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to use `col-xs-4` rather than `col-xs-1` to create the three columns so that it spans all twelve of the Bootstrap grid columns.

Comment: Simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `offset` to center your columns like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-4">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            Block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/12/

Comment: offset-4 adds 4 columns to the left of the wrapped class btw

Comment: Offsets work, but is there a way i can get a more precise centering? sometimes offsets push the grid a little bit to the left or right

Comment: Offset is actually very accurate as it follows the rest of the div columns and it is also way more cleaner than hacking the columns and rows with extra `floats` `margins` and `positions`

Answer (score 0):

You need wrapper. Try with `<div class="container">Your code here</div>`

**EDIT**

The question was edited after that comment.

Comment: Ah, it's already in a <div class="container">  can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @wolfgang It wasn't when you posted your question. Try to post a ***complete*** example of the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only using 3 out of 12 possible columns in Bootstrap. The columns, by default, run from left to right. A full 12 columns would look like this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That HTML represents 12 columns, spanning the entire width of the `.container`. But since you are using only 3 divs, each 1 column in size, all 3 columns are on the left side of the `.container`.

If you want 3 columns that span the entire size of the `.container` do this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
```

If you want 3, single-column divs that are centered in the `.container` it's a bit more complicated since the result of 12-3 = 9 is not divisible by 2. Since it's not divisible by 2 you can't have equal size space on the left and right side of the 3 columns. In order to get around this problem you need to do a nested (sub)grid similar to this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is essentially a 3 column within another grid.

That will create 3 divs, but the first will be offset (or pushed) to the right 4 columns, which will make all 3 columns appeared to be centered in the layout

Comment: It won't be centered as there will be an offset of 4 on the left and 5 on the right. You will have to create a bigger column in the middle and resplit it with another row.

Answer (score 0):

The [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) has 12 columns. If you want 3 equal 'columns', they each have to be 12/3 = 4 'gridcolumns' wide.

You're html will then look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Block</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Block</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, it's 12/3 = 4. And if your divs are 4 columns wide for all breakpoints then it's only necessary to specify the `xs` column size. The bigger breakpoints will inherit it.